# Trying to implement slide animation to TabView on ios (native api)

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, nativescript, native

I want to add slide animation to TabView on ios. I like the way it's implemented on android and I want to get the same result on ios using natvie api.

Unfortunately after clicking on new tab theres no animation, new tabitem is blank and app is turning off :(

home.component.ts

```
onSelectedIndexChanged(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {
    const fromIndex = args.oldIndex;
    const toIndex = args.newIndex;
    const tabView = <TabView>args.object;
    const tabIOS: UITabBarController = tabView.ios;

    const tabViewControllers: Array<UIViewController> = Array.from(tabIOS.viewControllers);
    const fromView: UIView = tabViewControllers[fromIndex].view;
    const toView: UIView = tabViewControllers[toIndex].view;

    tabIOS.setViewControllersAnimated(tabIOS.viewControllers, true);
    fromView.addSubview(toView);

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width;
    let scrollRight = toIndex > fromIndex;
    let offset = (scrollRight ? screenWidth : -screenWidth);
    toView.center = new CGPoint({
      x: fromView.center.x + offset,
      y: toView.center.y
    });


    UIView.animateWithDurationAnimationsCompletion(0.6, () => {
      const fromCenter: CGPoint = new CGPoint({
        x: fromView.center.x - offset,
        y: fromView.center.y
      });

      const toCenter: CGPoint = new CGPoint({
        x: toView.center.x - offset,
        y: toView.center.y
      });
      fromView.center = fromCenter;
      toView.center = toCenter;

    }, () => {
      fromView.removeFromSuperview();
      tabIOS.selectedIndex = toIndex;
    })
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you may able to achieve what you are looking for from selectedIndexChange event, unless you just want to slide the new tab content in. Because by the time selectedIndexChange is triggered, old tab would have been already removed, you may not able to perform slide out animation there. Moreover the iOS equivalent of Android TabView (ViewPager) is [UIPageViewController](https://medium.com/swift-india/android-like-tabs-in-ios-sliding-tabs-segments-4dc38d801463) which provides sliding between pages by default. You will have to design your own TabBar if you go with this control.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Manoj. How should create own/custom component based on TabView instead of implementing 'native code' in selectedIndexChange? There are some tutorials how to implement slide animation in swift but I don't know where to start if I want to use this code in nativescript :( Are you able to help me in this case?